# Datastage-What is the escape character for # in execute command activity?

Tags: datastage

What is the escape character for # in execute command activity? Well i was trying to replace one string in file with "#",but datastage treating # as job parameter and expecting the value to be assigned in datastage parameters.For that we need escape character for "#". I tried using \ and / as escape characters but none of them solved my problem. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use awk to replace the # sign, and you can use the octal character code for # in the regular expression:

```
!/^\043/
```

[There is a thread in DSXchange that discusses this.](http://www.dsxchange.com/viewtopic.php?p=419492)

[Here is a guide on escape sequences in AWK expressions.](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html)

[A table with ascii codes, including a column for octal values.](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that the actual answer to this question is:
    `\043`
The expression mentioned previously (`!/^\043/`) is related to the first link @Damienknight posted.